# Generating PDFs with Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pdf-generation

I want to generate a PDF using the following approach found on the Django 1.9 docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf.

Here is my url pattern (I don't need anything special, just a different url name like so

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^people/$', PeopleTemplate.as_view(), name='people'),
   url(r'^people/pdf/$', some_view),
 ]

  def some_view(request):
      response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'
      p = canvas.Canvas(response)
      p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
      p.showPage()
      p.save()

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          context = locals()
          context['response'] = self.response
          context['p'] = self.p
          return render_to_response(self.response_template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm trying to use a get method. This prompts for a pdf output when I hit /pdf, but doesn't contain any data - just a blank page. How do I get data that exists at this url /attendance/ to show on the pdf page when you hit the /attendance/pdf url?

Comment: try the complex pdfs tutorial below the one you are looking at, maybe thatll work.

Comment: yeah tried that too, same result

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to:

1. render html
2. convert it to pdf
3. set pdf content to response body
4. return response

Now your code renders template as html, adds 'application/pdf' content type to headers and returns normal html page.

You need something like PDFTemplateView. There are ready to use packages  [django-easy-pdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pdf/0.1.0) or [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wkhtmltopdf/2.0.3).

UPD:

```
  def some_view(request):
      response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'
      p = canvas.Canvas(response)

      // simple but visual result is not pretty at all
      for i, obj in enumerate(People.objects.all()):
          p.drawString(100, 50*(i+1), str(obj))

      p.showPage()
      p.save()

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          context = locals()
          context['response'] = self.response
          context['p'] = self.p
          return render_to_response(self.response_template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I updated my question. I can get the pdf prompt now, but no data in it. Check out my updated question.

Comment: Try to save file and check its size. Try to open saved file with another viewer. Try to draw something else on pdf canvas and repeat first steps.

Comment: If you see response, now you need to add normal data to pdf using reportlab API. First get data from db using Django orm (something like People.objects.all()). Then iterate through it and add it to pdf canvas.

Comment: I get this error on that code "object has no attribute '__unicode__'"

Comment: code converts obj to unicode string, try to replace "obj.__unicode__()" with  "str(obj)". I use Python 2.7.

Comment: k thanks that worked, just not sure if iterating through the all object is the best approach, but I'm going to play with it a bit

Comment: There is an option to filter data using django filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters and there is queryset iterator for large data lists https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#iterator